# Reflection of generic method not working

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, methods, static

I have a generic static method which registers a interface and I need to write that using c# reflection.

```
Services.AddService<ITBroker>(new TBrokerService());
```

I tried following code but it is not working

```
Type[] externTBrokerService = Assembly.LoadFrom("Business.dll").GetTypes();
Type[] externService = Assembly.LoadFrom("ServiceModel.dll").GetTypes();
Type iTBroker = externITBroker[12];
MethodInfo method = externService[1].GetMethods()[2];
//Gets Add Service method
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(iTBroker);
//Make method generic           
generic.Invoke(null,new object[] { externTBrokerService[0]});
//invoke the service
```

Above code gives me very generic exception of parameters.

What is the write way to write reflection for above code?

Comment: What `externService`? Why are you sure, that the 3rd method in array is `AddService<T>`?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: And what is the value of `iTBroker`? There's far too little information to go on here. If you could produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make life a lot clearer. (And you should *never* rely on the order of methods or types like this.)

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ: Exception i am getting is _Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'DataCollection.IBroker'._

Comment: Note that `externTBrokerService[0]` is a `Type` and not an instance of  that type.

Comment: @Dennis - The reason i am sure it is AddServie<T> because signature of AddService is 'public static void AddService<T>(T instance) where T : IDisposable;'.

Comment: @Kartik: so what? `Type.GetTypes()` overload returns all public methods. There's no signature checking in this overload. The order of items in array is an implementation detail. There's no guarantee, that 3rd item will be desired `AddService<T>`. The same is true for `Assembly.GetTypes()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have edited the code and added value of ITBroker. I will try to write up some code which is more useful.

Comment: @Rafal: You've nailed it. I suggest you write that up as an answer.

Comment: @Kartik: If you'd included the information about the exception you were getting (which isn't a "very generic exception of parameters" - it's a very specific exception saying that it can't convert type X to type Y) from the start, including which line was throwing the exception, this would have been a lot simpler to spot. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @Dennis - Sorry. I misread your previous comments. Please ignore that, What i did was, i placed a debugger and checked that 3rd item is AddService<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was in comments:

Note that `externTBrokerService[0]` is a `Type` and not an instance of that type.

Having that I feel a need to include sense of other comments as part of my answer.

```
Type iTBroker = externITBroker[12];
```

this is wrong! And sooner or later this will fail to find your type as the order of types in this collection is undetermined and can change. You should do it like this:

```
Type iTBroker = externITBroker.Single(x => x.Name == "ITBroker");
```

This is far form foolproof so be sure that the condition gives you unique result.

or simply load that type directly by (assuming that this is the AssemblyQualifiedName of your type):

```
Type.GetType("Business.ITBroker, Business");
```

To find method on your type there is a method `Type.GetMethod` one of its overloads will be sufficient to find your method.

To create instance of your type that needs to be passed as argument you can use

```
Activator.CreateInstance(brokerServiceType);
```